Extremely short-output hash for unique id generation
For some backstory, I'm looking for a way to squeeze a system identifier into as few bytes as possible (4 would be ideal), as part of a compact guid (the 128 bits in standard solutions are too much). The id must be "global" only within a closed ecosystem with up to a few hundred participating nodes - all trusted, non-adversarial, but no shared registry or otherwise a way to synchronize them.
Due to lack of many other options, I'm considering just traditional (in the programming sense) fixed-length hashcodes of self-reported application names, but without the hashmap, so I need reasonable collision-resistance and I don't get that from non-cryptographic hashes.
So ... let's say I have a couple hundred nodes following a naming convention like cluster_subgroup_workername, where workername is variable-length, but no longer than let's say 30 ASCII characters. Is it reasonable to expect BLAKE2 with the output size set to the ridiculously low 4 bytes to be good enough? Or perhaps truncating the output of another hash function? Or am I better off just getting 4 random bytes during each app's startup, and hoping the anecdotal 1:2^32 chance of random collision is good enough (which sounds very tempting, but my gut feeling is to avoid)?

According to this answer (which relates to CRC-32, but the results should be close enough for any random number/hash truncation) with 300 nodes you have a 1 in 100,000 chance of collision.
This does not depend on how you generate your 32-bit value, as (for this purpose) hashes and real randomness are indistinguishable.  I believe the same could be said for CRC-32 as well.
If 1 in 100000 is not good enough odds, you need more bits.

The probability of collision with $k$ nodes assigned uniformly random values in $[0,n)$ is $$p=1-\frac{n!}{(n-k)!,n^k}=1-\frac{\binom n k,k!}{n^k}$$For $k=300$, $n=2^{32}$ as in this answer, this yields $p\approx0.000,010,442,4\approx1/95,763.4$, indeed close to "1 in 100,000 chance". But this goes up fast with $k$: For $k=50,000$ we get $p\gtrsim\frac 14$.
